# Hadoop - Difference between single large node and multiple small node

Tags: hadoop

I am new in hadoop. I am wondering are there any different between single node and multi-node, if both have same computing power.

For example, there is one server with 4 cores CPU and 32 GB RAM to setup a single node hadoop. On the other hand, there are four servers with one core CPE (same clock rate with the "big" server) and 8GB RAM to setup a 4 node hadoop cluster. Which setup would be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always better to have more number of data nodes instead of one powerful node. Basically we need to configure Name node with high configuration and data nodes can have less configurations.

So, if you have single node, all the demons will be running in the same node with single JVM, where as if you have multiple nodes the demons can run parallelly (sequentially) with multiple JVMs.